# Перечислить все поля и их значения C#

Tags: c#

Нужно для отладки прочитать название всех полей класса и их значения. 
Ну например, имеется экземпляр класса dog

```
class dog
{
public int age = 3;
public string name = "barboss";
public bool isHungry = false;
}
```

Как мне, не зная сходу названия полей, просто получить на выходе что то типа такого

```
dog:{int age 3, string name "barboss,bool isHungry false};
```

Comment: Подключить JSON.NET и сериализовать

Comment: @АндрейNOP, подключать библиотеку для отладки? о_О

Comment: Да можно сериализовать и встроенными средствами, но ответ Игоря более красивый и правильный.

Comment: @Qwertiy, это то же самое, что решение с рефлексией, но уже готовое и отлаженное. К тому же валидный json будет гораздо проще разбирать.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, во-первых, я не уверен, что json читать удобнее. Во-вторых, если библиотека уже подключена - то ok, но если нет, то ставить лишнюю библиотеку и менять зависимости проекта ради отладки (и потом не забыть это откатить) - это как-то перебор - не кажется?

Comment: @Qwertiy, перебор или нет - решать автору, библиотека не такая уж и большая, зато работает быстрее аналогов. Ну и не читать, а разбирать я написал. Библиотечное решение учтет такие нюансы, как встречающиеся кавычки в строке, например, и прочие. Так что как вариант, это решение имеет право на существование. С другой стороны, вместо JSON.NET можно подключить библиотеку для логирования, можно будет найти ту, которая умеет выводить свойства объекта в лог. Это будет ещё более правильное решение.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
object bobik = new dog();
foreach(FieldInfo field in bobik.GetType().GetFields())
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", field.FieldType, field.Name, field.GetValue(bobik));
}
```